# Why is a contractive algebra homomorphism between C*-algebras necessarily a C*-homomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose Φ is an algebra homomorphism from a unital C*-algebra into another unital C*-algebra. How to prove that if $\| \Phi(x)\| \le \|x\|$ for all $x$, then $\Phi$ is a C*-homomophism? In other words: How to prove that $\Phi$ preserves involutions? This is an exercise from Kehe Zhu's "An introduction to operator algebras".

Comment: I've tried to look at the norm of $\Phi(x)^*-\Phi(x^*)$. But without much succes. I've also thought about if the Gelfand transform could be useful, somehow. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\Phi(1)=1$ it follows that $\Phi(x^{-1})=\Phi(x)^{-1}$ for each invertible $x$ in the domain.  In particular, if $u$ is unitary, then $\Phi(u)$ and $\Phi(u^*)$ are inverses of one another with norm at most $1$.  If you will take for granted that $C^*$-algebras are $*$-isomorphic to $C^*$-algebras of operators on Hilbert space, this shows that $\Phi(u)$ is unitary and $\Phi(u^*)=\Phi(u)^{*}$.  (If $T\in B(H)$ is invertible and $\|Tx\|\neq \|x\|$ for some $x$, then either $T$ or $T^{-1}$ has norm greater than $1$.)

Because $\Phi$ preserves involutions on unitary elements and $C^*$-algebras are spanned by their unitary elements, $\Phi$ preserves involutions.

---

Added: Without appealing to representation on Hilbert space, but (implicitly) using Gelfand theory or other means of knowledge about positive elements on $C^*$-algebras, here's proof that if $\|x\|=\|x^{-1}\|=1$ then $x$ is unitary.

Note that $\sigma(x^*x)^{-1}=\sigma((x^*x)^{-1})=\sigma(x^{-1}(x^{-1})^*)$.  Because $x^*x$ and $x^{-1}(x^{-1})^*$ are positive with norm $1$, they have spectrum contained in $(0,1]$.  Hence $\sigma(x^*x)=\{1\}$ which implies $x^*x=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I can follow the reasoning in that argument, but how is it clear, that if T∈B(H) is invertible and ∥Tx∥≠∥x∥ for some $x$, then either $T$ or $T^{-1}$ has norm greater than 1?

Comment: @Kimarokko: $\|T\|\geq\dfrac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$ and $\|T^{-1}\|\geq\dfrac{\|x\|}{\|Tx\|}$.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I think it is also possible to prove the statement without using the Gelfand-Naimak-Segal construction (since that theorem is several chapters ahead in the book), but the prove above is fine enough for me.

Comment: I'm sure it is.  My guess is it would be fruitful to try to show that $\Phi$ preserves self-adjointness.  But in the context of my answer, I'd be curious for a simple proof for an abstract $C^*$-algebra that if $\|x\|\leq 1$ and $\|x^{-1}\|\leq 1$, then $x$ is unitary.  (Maybe I'll ask as another question.)

Comment: @Kimarokko: I added a way to see $\Phi(u)$ is unitary without appealing to representation on Hilbert space.

Comment: In your addition to the proof, you assume that the norm of both $x$ and $x^{-1}$ is 1. Shouldn't is be less than or equal to 1?

Comment: @Kimarokko: It makes no difference, the same argument applies.  In any case, because $\|ab\|\leq\|a\|\|b\|$ it follows that $\|x^{-1}\|\geq \dfrac{1}{\|x\|}$ and $\|x\|\geq\dfrac{1}{\|x^{-1}\|}$ so if the norms are less than or equal to $1$ they are equal to one.  Nonetheless, sorry if the change made my answer seem more obscure.  It seemed a simpler way to phrase it and loses no generality.

Comment: Right. Your answer may be a bit hard to read, but it makes sense if work a bit on the details. Nice arguments.