# How can I prove, that my constructed spectral measure $E(\Delta)$ is an orthogonal projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory

**Definitions**

*Representation*

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}(X)$. Also, we denote $L(H)$ as the set of all linear operators on HIlbert space $H$.

We call $\Phi : \mathcal{A} \ni u \rightarrow \Phi(u) \in L(H)$ a representation, if:

1. $\Phi$ is linear and multiplicative
2. $\Phi(e) = I_H$, where $e$ is the neutral multiplicative element of the algebra $\mathcal{A}$
3. There exists a $K > 0$ such, that $\| \Phi(u) \| \le K \|u \|$ for all $u \in \mathcal{A}$

*Measure $\mu_{xy}$*

A measure $\mu_{xy}$ is called the "elementary measure for $\Phi$", if for any $x,y \in H$:

$$\langle \Phi(u) x, y \rangle = \int_X u(z) d\mu_{xy}$$ for $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le K \| x \| \|y \|$.

*Spectral measure*

On a Borel set $\mathcal{B}$ in $\Omega$, we call $E : \mathcal{B} \ni \Delta \rightarrow E(\Delta) \in B(H)$ a spectral measure, if:

1. $E(\Omega) = I_H$, $E(\varnothing) = 0$
2. $E(\Delta)$ is an orthogonal projection in $H$ for all $\Delta$
3. $E(\bigcup_{n}^{\infty} \Delta_n) = \sum_{n}^{\infty} E(\Delta_n)$ for all disjunctive $\Delta_n$

**Important:** In this context, we will assume, that $\Phi$ is a natural representation ("functional calculus") of an $N$-tuple of operators $(T_1, \ldots, T_N)$, i.e.

$$\Phi(u) := u(T_1, \ldots, T_n)$$

---

How can I prove, that my spectral measure $E(\Delta)$ constructed in the following way:

$$\mu_{xy} (\Delta) = \langle E(\Delta) x, y \rangle$$

is an orthogonal projection (i.e. it satisfies $E(\Delta)^* = E(\Delta)$ and $E(\Delta)^2 = E(\Delta)$)?

I've heard from my professor (I'm a 1st year PhD student) that it is important that in this context $K = 1$, but why? I can't find anything on the internet about that.

Comment: For $\Phi$ defined by functional calculus, $\Phi$ can be extended to a $\ast$-homomorphism so it’s already of norm 1.

Comment: Self-adjointness follows from observing that $\mu_{x, x}$ is a real-valued measure. Being an idempotent follows from first arguing, for a continuous $f$, $\mu_{\Phi(f)x, y} = f\mu_{x, y}$, then this implies $\Phi(g)\Phi(f) = \Phi(gf)$ for Borel $g$ and continuous $f$. ($\Phi$ can be extended to bounded Borel functions in the same way you defined $E(\Delta)$ - this is known as Borel functional calculus.) Then this implies $\mu_{\Phi(g)x, y} = g\mu_{x, y}$ for Borel $g$, so $\Phi(g)\Phi(f) = \Phi(gf)$ holds for Borel $g$ and $f$. In particular, as $E(\Delta) = \Phi(1_\Delta)$, it’s idempotent

Comment: @DavidGao But that's not always the case. Let's say $\Phi(p) := p(T_1, \ldots, T_N)$ where $p$ is a polynomial on the polydisc $\mathbb{D}^N$ (alternatively, you can take the disc algebra i.e. $p \in A(\mathbb{D}^n)$). Then, if $(T_1, \ldots, T_N)$ is a tuple of commuting contractions, then for $N \ge 3$, we will definitely not have $K=1$ here (unless you additionally assume the Brehmer condition for example). So in this case, we will have $K>1$. And apparently, this creates a difficulty in constructing a spectral measure from $\mu_{xy}$. And my question is: Why? Why is $K=1$ so important?

Comment: I should point out that if you want a spectral measure, then $T_i$ have to be commuting normal operators, in which case $\Phi$ can be extended to a $\ast$-homomorphisms. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidGao Unfortunately, no. I just don't understand, why the assumption $K = 1$ is important here in constructing the spectral measure $E(\Delta)$ (and especially showing, that $E(\Delta)$ is an orthogonal projection).

Comment: Perhaps you would be satisfied with a proof that, if you get a spectral measure through this procedure, then your representation is necessarily a $\ast$-homomorphism and therefore of norm 1?

Comment: @DavidGao I think yes, I would really appreciate a proof. This could actually help me a lot in what I'm currently working on if I think about it.

Comment: @DavidGao Although my Professor has told me that I should check this for $K > 1$, so it's a bit odd right now. Because on the one hand, my professor is telling me to generalize this case for $K > 1$, but on the other hand, you're telling me that it's impossible and that $K=1$ is always the case no matter what.

Comment: It might be your professor is asking you to find for yourself what can go wrong if $K > 1$. Regardless, $K = 1$ is necessarily the case, and I’ve provided a proof as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a proof that, suppose you have a collection of complex-valued measures $\{\mu_{x, y}\}_{x, y \in H}$ on $\Omega$ such that $E(\Delta)$ defined by $\mu_{x, y}(\Delta) = \langle E(\Delta)x, y\rangle$ forms a spectral measure, then there exists a $\ast$-homomorphism (hence of norm 1) $\Phi: C(\Omega) \rightarrow B(H)$ s.t. $\mu_{x, y}$ is the elementary measure for $\Phi$.

We observe that as $\mu_{x, y}(\Delta) = \langle E(\Delta)x, y\rangle$ defines a bounded linear operator for all $\Delta$, we already have $\mu_{x, y}$ is sesquilinear in $x$ and $y$. Now, we show that $||\mu_{x, y}|| \leq ||x||||y||$. Let $f = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i 1_{\Delta_i}$ be a simple function and we may assume $\Delta_i$ are disjoint. Then,

$$\int f d\mu_{x, y} = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \mu_{x, y}(\Delta_i) =  \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \langle E(\Delta_i)x, y\rangle = \langle (\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i E(\Delta_i))x, y\rangle$$

Since $\Delta_i$ are disjoint, $E(\Delta_i)$ are pairwise orthogonal (you can easily get this from condition 3 in your definition of spectral measures). Hence, $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i E(\Delta_i)$ has operator norm the maximum of $|a_i|$, the same as the sup norm of $f$. Thus, $|\int f d\mu_{x, y}| \leq ||f||_\infty||x||||y||$, so $||\mu_{x, y}|| \leq ||x||||y||$.

This already tells you $K = 1$, but let’s keep going to construct $\Phi$. This is simply given by $\int u \mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(u)x, y\rangle$. Since $||\mu_{x, y}|| \leq ||x||||y||$, $\Phi(u)$ is a well-defined bounded operator of norm at most $||u||_\infty$. This can also be defined for bounded Borel $u$, which is known as the Borel functional calculus. To see that $\Phi(u)$ is self-adjoint whenever $u$ is, we see that, as $E(\Delta)$ is self-adjoint, $\mu_{x, x} = \langle E(\cdot)x, x\rangle$ is a real-valued measure. So if $u$ is self-adjoint, that is, a real-valued function, then $\langle \Phi(u)x, x\rangle = \int u \mu_{x, x}$ is real, so $\Phi(u)$ is self-adjoint. Proving multiplicativity is more annoying - we consider $\Phi$ as extended to all bounded Borel functions, defined the same way. Observe that $E(\Delta_1)E(\Delta_2) = E(\Delta_1 \cap \Delta_2)$. (Again, this follows from condition 3.) Also observe that $\Phi(\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i 1_{\Delta_i}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i E(\Delta_i)$, as we have seen before. Then clearly $\Phi$ is multiplicative on simple functions, i.e., for simple functions $u$ and $v$,

$$\int u (v d\mu_{x, y}) = \int (uv) d\mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(uv)x, y\rangle = \langle \Phi(u)\Phi(v)x, y\rangle = \int u d\mu_{\Phi(v)x, y}$$

This holds for all simple $u$, so $v\mu_{x, y} = \mu_{\Phi(v)x, y}$. But then we can repeat the above argument with now $u$ bounded Borel and $v$ simple,

$$\langle \Phi(u)\Phi(v)x, y\rangle = \int u d\mu_{\Phi(v)x, y} = \int u (v d\mu_{x, y}) = \int (uv) d\mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(uv)x, y\rangle$$

So $\Phi(u)\Phi(v) = \Phi(uv)$ whenever $u$ is bounded Borel and $v$ is simple. Repeat the argument again with $u$ bounded Borel and $v$ simple,

$$\int v (u d\mu_{x, y}) = \int (uv) d\mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(uv)x, y\rangle = \langle \Phi(u)\Phi(v)x, y\rangle = \langle \Phi(v)x, \Phi(u)^\ast y\rangle = \int v d\mu_{x, \Phi(u)^\ast y}$$

So $u \mu_{x, y} = \mu_{x, \Phi(u)^\ast y}$ for all bounded Borel $u$. Finally, for $u$, $v$ both bounded Borel,

$$\langle \Phi(u)\Phi(v)x, y\rangle = \langle \Phi(v)x, \Phi(u)^\ast y\rangle = \int v d\mu_{x, \Phi(u)^\ast y} = \int v (u d\mu_{x, y}) = \int (uv) d\mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(uv)x, y\rangle$$

That is, $\Phi(u)\Phi(v) = \Phi(uv)$ for all bounded Borel $u$ and $v$, in particular continuous ones. So $\Phi$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism. By construction, $\mu_{x, y}$ is the elementary measure for $\Phi$.

Comment: Thanks. Your proof makes sense, but now I am more confused. The theorem I am working with is the "Main Theorem" on page 7 (https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6b8013dd522cda6bdd62c2722357b8fc1134a5a8). And what my Professor wants me to check is what happens if $K > 1$. I told him that there is no use of the von Neumann inequality (i.e. $K = 1$) in the proof of this theorem. He told me that "it is important for $K=1$, because otherwise, we won't get a spectral measure out of $\mu_{xy}$". And this is what I'm trying to figure out: How exactly don't we get it?

Comment: @S-F I worked through the proof myself. While the proof doesn't seem to use $K = 1$ anywhere, it is in fact necessary for this line to work: "We note, by Theorem 1 of [11], that we should only check that $T = (T_1, \cdots, T_N)$ has property (F)." This is because [11] assumes throughout that representations are contractive, i.e., $K = 1$. Now, the reason it is necessary for [11], as it turns out, is this line around the middle of page 313, in the proof of its Theorem 1 (the theorem used in the paper you linked):

Comment: @S-F "Hence by [7], Theorem 4.2, $S_p'$ can be extended to a $\ast$-representation of $C(\Gamma_{j_1, \cdots, j_m})$ with spectral measure singular to $R_{j_1, \cdots, j_m}^\perp$." This is interesting because nowhere does this cited [7] mentions $\ast$-representation. It only deals with Banach algebras there. The reason this works is because Theorem 4.2 in [7] says the extended representation $T^{\mathrm{ext}}$ has the same norm as that of $T$, so $T^{\mathrm{ext}}$ is contractive iff $T$ is.

Comment: How did you find paper [11]? I can't find it on the internet.

Comment: @S-F For an algebra homomorphism $S$ between $C^\ast$-algebras, as it turns out, $S$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism iff it is contractive. See, for example, this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172807/why-is-a-contractive-algebra-homomorphism-between-c-algebras-necessarily-a-c-h . And this is why $K = 1$ is used - without that condition you cannot extend the relevant measures from the subalgebra (if I'm not mistaken, it's basically some subalgebra of the disc algebra) to the whole algebra of continuous functions.

Comment: @S-F A link to [11], Representation generated by a finite number of Hilbert space operators: https://eudml.org/doc/265819 . A link to [7] cited in [11], Decompositions of non-contractive operator-valued representations of Banach algebras: https://eudml.org/doc/217651

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help, you helped me so much right now!

Comment: @S-F A further comment: In fact, to uniquely define $\mu_{x, y}$, you already need $\mathcal{A} = C(X)$, or at least a dense subalgebra of it, since $\mu_{x, y}$ defined by $\int u d\mu_{x, y} = \langle \Phi(u)x, y\rangle$ is only a linear functional on $\mathcal{A}$ - and the space of Radon measures on $X$ is the space of linear functionals on the entirety of $C(X)$. In particular, for, say $X = \mathbb{D}$, there are actually measures which evaluate to 0 on all analytic functions but is not the zero measure...

Comment: @S-F So you need to extend your representation to all continuous functions to uniquely define $\mu_{x, y}$, and in order to ensure $E(\Delta)$ is self-adjoint, you need the representation to be a $\ast$-representation, which is equivalent to $\mu_{x, x}$ being real-valued and then equivalent to $E(\Delta)$ being self-adjoint. This is why [11] needs to extend to a $\ast$-representation of the algebra of all continuous functions to get a spectral measure to which they can then apply the assumption of property (F). They ensure they can get a $\ast$-representation by proving it's contractive.

Comment: @S-F Glad to have helped. As a suggestion, next time you see a result proved seemingly without a condition being used, try search through the cited theorems used in the proof - usually you will end up finding out why the condition is there.